# ff Function created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

```
create or replace function cart_jaune(code in equipe.num_eq%type) return integer as    
  nb integer := 0;
begin
  select count(*)
    into nb
    from sanctionner s, joueur j
   where s.code_joueur = j.code_joueur
     and j.num_eq = code
     and s.type_catron like '%jaune%';
  return nb;
end;
/
```

Comment: What do you get as error message? Btw, initializing the local variable `nb` is redundant, since it will already yield zero if none of matching record returns.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on tool you use, you should check *which* error you got. Because, how is anyone supposed to assist? What works regardless of a tool is querying `user_errors`. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number is
  2  begin
  3    retval := 1;         --> variable isn't declared, so - compilation will fail
  4    return retval;
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> select line, position, text from user_errors where name = 'F_TEST' order by line, position;

 LINE  POSITION TEXT
----- --------- --------------------------------------------------
    3         3 PLS-00201: identifier 'RETVAL' must be declared
    3         3 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    4         3 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    4        10 PLS-00201: identifier 'RETVAL' must be declared
```

Or, in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> show err
Errors for FUNCTION F_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/3      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3/3      PLS-00201: identifier 'RETVAL' must be declared
4/3      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/10     PLS-00201: identifier 'RETVAL' must be declared
SQL>
```

So, sooner you tell us what's wrong, sooner we'll be able to help.

---

Meanwhile, I created sample tables you used in your function. Everything seems to be OK.

```
SQL> create table equipe(num_eq number);

Table created.

SQL> create table sanctionner (code_joueur number, type_catron varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table joueur (code_joueur number, num_eq number);

Table created.
```

Function: I didn't change anything, just formatted it a little bit:

```
SQL> create or replace function cart_jaune(code in equipe.num_eq%type)
  2    return integer
  3  as
  4    nb integer := 0;
  5  begin
  6    select count(*)
  7    into nb
  8    from sanctionner  s,
  9         joueur       j
 10    where s.code_joueur = j.code_joueur
 11      and j.num_eq = code
 12      and s.type_catron like '%jaune%';
 13
 14    return nb;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> select cart_jaune(1) from dual;

CART_JAUNE(1)
-------------
            0

SQL>
```

Yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the `code` value with the type `EQUIPE.NUM_EQ%TYPE` but compare it to the `JOUEUR.NUM_EQ` column. Unless you have two tables with the columns with the same name and data type then you probably wanted to declare the type in the signature to be `JOUEUR.NUM_EQ%TYPE`:

```sql
create or replace function cart_jaune(code in joueur.num_eq%type) return integer as    
  nb integer := 0;
begin
  select count(*)
    into nb
    from sanctionner s, joueur j
   where s.code_joueur = j.code_joueur
     and j.num_eq = code
     and s.type_catron like '%jaune%';
  return nb;
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bda212b8beb253f85fbe7bf89229d032)*

Answer (score 0):

AS others said, you need to show the error.  We shouldn't have to play a game of "Guess What's In My Pocket?"

That said, ansi JOIN syntax has been available for, what, 20 years?  You should use it:

```
select count(*)
  into nb
  from sanctionner  s,
    join joueur j on s.code_joueur = j.code_joueur
  where j.num_eq = code
  and s.type_catron like '%jaune%';
```

Helps insure you account for all of the joins.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're playing "guess my error message", here's mine:

In your SQL query, you refer to `code`:

```
     and j.num_eq = code
```

Since you have not provided any alias for `code`, the SQL engine will first try to match it to a column in any of the tables listed in your `FROM` clause.

If, for example, `sanctionner` has a column `code`, that will be what the SQL engine will use here, i.e.:

```
select count(*)
  into nb
  from sanctionner s, joueur j
 where s.code_joueur = j.code_joueur
   and j.num_eq = s.code
   and s.type_catron like '%jaune%';
```

Since you actually wanted it to bind your PL/SQL function parameter, you need to provide the alias, i.e.:

```
select count(*)
  into nb
  from sanctionner s, joueur j
 where s.code_joueur = j.code_joueur
   and j.num_eq = cart_jaune.code
   and s.type_catron like '%jaune%';
```

In fact, it's best practice to *always* provide aliases for all columns and binds, especially when embedding SQL within PL/SQL.